# Using an Raspberry Pi as a Z-Wave Sensor?

Tags: raspberry-pi, sensors, z-wave

I would like to make a sensor for the z-wave protocol.
The "sensor" is a raspberry pi, which do "something" and have to send the state (Integer Value or if possible: a String Value) via z-wave.

Is there any library for the raspberry z-wave module, which can create such a "virtual z-wave device"?

Thanks in advance! :)

Answer (score 1):

Please have a look at the Razberry [project](http://razberry.z-wave.me/).

They have a server, running on raspberry pi, which communicates with the razberry daughter board. You can use HTTP API to communicate with it or work with their C library.